# MS Access query, how to create a file inventory query showing only the most recent date a file has changed location

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to use MS-Access to create a database of files. These files can be charged out to employees for review.

I have a table for the inventory, a table for employees, and a "charge out" table that includes a file, what employee it is being charged out to, and the date this happened.

My goal is to create a query that shows the file inventory and its details, and the location as to where it is currently located (e.g. with an employee, or in storage).

I have the following query called Most_Recent_Change:

```
        SELECT Inventory.File_Number, Inventory.Last_Name, Inventory.First_Name, 
        Max([Charge_In/Out].Date_Changed) AS Current_Location_Date
        FROM Inventory INNER JOIN [Charge_In/Out] ON Inventory.HRMIS = [Charge_In/Out].File_HRMIS
        GROUP BY Inventory.File_Number, Inventory.Last_Name, Inventory.First_Name;
```

This returns the information from the file, and the most recent date from the charge out table.

What I need is this table, with each file from the inventory **showing up exactly once**, with the most recent date, but I also need the location that is associated with the most current date. Adding the location to this query creates duplicates from the inventory which I cannot have.

I created another query which I believe is more complete:

```
    SELECT Inventory.File_Number, Inventory.Last_Name, Inventory.First_Name, [Charge_In/Out].Date_Changed AS 
    Current_Location_Date, Location.Location_Name
    FROM Location INNER JOIN (Inventory INNER JOIN [Charge_In/Out] ON Inventory.File_Number = 
    [Charge_In/Out].File_Number) ON Location.Location_Name = [Charge_In/Out].Charge_Out_Location
    WHERE Current_Location_Date =
            (SELECT MAX(Date_Changed)
            FROM [Charge_In/Out]);
```

This prompts access to ask for the parameter value for Current_Location_Date, which it should not be, it should be taking the max date for each entry in the inventory.

For reference, this is what the Charge out table looks like:

```
     LogNumber | File_Number | Charge_Out_Location | Date_Changed
        1            xxx1             Storage         2019-01-01
        2            xxx1             Analyst         2020-05-01
        3            xxx1             Storage         2020-10-02
        4            xxx2             Storage         2019-01-01
```

And the resulting table that I need would look like:

```
    File_Number | Last_Name | First_Name | Current_Location | Current_Location_Date
       xxx1         SMITH        John          Storage             2020-10-02
       xxx2         SMITH        Jane          Storage             2019-01-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using your first result-set like a virtual table.

```
SELECT Inventory.File_Number, Inventory.Last_Name, Inventory.First_Name, 
   MaxInventory.Current_Location_Date, Charge.Charge_Out_Location
FROM Inventory
   INNER JOIN (
       SELECT Inventory.File_Number, Max([Charge_In/Out].Date_Changed) AS Current_Location_Date
       FROM Inventory INNER JOIN [Charge_In/Out] ON Inventory.HRMIS = [Charge_In/Out].File_HRMIS
       GROUP BY Inventory.File_Number
    ) AS MaxInventory ON Inventory.File_Number = MaxInventory.File_Number
    INNER JOIN [Charge_In/Out] AS Charge ON Inventory.HRMIS = Charge.File_HRMIS 
          AND Charge.Date_Changed = MaxInventory.Current_Location_Date
```

The concept is to get the summary as a virtual table (ie "query"). It has minimum info, so it is easy to join-to, and without duplicate lines. Give it an alias `MaxInventory`. Then join the rest of your info to `MaxInventory`, which is already minimized/summarized.

You can also just create a new "query" in MS Access to do the same thing, and it is more-permanent, instead of creating it inline, like I did.

The query changes when you have multiple check-ins for the same date and you only want the newest, per-file:

```
SELECT Inventory.File_Number, Inventory.Last_Name, Inventory.First_Name, 
   Charge.Date_Changed AS Current_Location_Date, Charge.Charge_Out_Location
FROM (
       SELECT Inventory.File_Number, Max([Charge_In/Out].LogNumber) AS MaxLogNumber
       FROM Inventory INNER JOIN [Charge_In/Out] ON Inventory.HRMIS = [Charge_In/Out].File_HRMIS
       GROUP BY Inventory.File_Number
    ) AS MaxCharge 
    INNER JOIN [Charge_In/Out] AS Charge ON MaxCharge.MaxLogNumber = Charge.LogNumber
    INNER JOIN Inventory ON Inventory.File_Number = MaxCharge.File_Number
      AND Inventory.HRMIS = Charge.File_HRMIS
```

Comment: Where would I put the JOIN for the Location Table in this solution? I created the MaxInventory as a separate query, then using the rest of the query as you suggested. Access then asks for a parameter value for Location.Location_Name

Comment: Oh. Good catch.  I didn't link it.  I'll change my answer.

Comment: Using this leads to a similar problem that I had before. Everything works as it should, except there are multiple entries for the same file. Using the tables I provided as an example above, there are three entries for file number xxx1, one location being storage, then analyst, then storage again, all with the most recent date of 2020/10/02. Is there any way to make it so there is only one entry for each file?

Comment: Ah yes.  I also need to link the date.  Of course, if there are multiple entries for the same date, there are more things to do.  Is that a possible scenario?

Comment: Do you have a primary key (auto-number) column on the [Charge_in/out] table? Is it numbered sequentially (higest=newest)

Comment: Yes, there is an auto number PK in that table. Highest would be the most recent

Comment: Could you tell me the name of the column, so I can update this query?

Comment: It's called LogNumber